# Firestore Rule not applying to collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a `Routines` collection where documents that have a field `programId` should not be allowed to be readable.

I have this firestore rule:

```
match /Routines/{routineId=**} {
    allow write: if false;
    allow read: if !('programId' in resource.data);
}
```

When I get a document from this collection, the rules work as supposed to but when I get the whole collection, I get all documents, even the documents that have a `programId` set. So it seems like the rule does not apply to the collection.

I get the collection like this:

```
const res = await firebase.firestore().collection("Routines").get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that [Firestore security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query).  Be sure to read and understand that documentation, as well as [this post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-does-it-mean-that-firestore-security-rules-are-not-filters-68ec14f3d003).  Your query is asking for **all** of the documents in the Routines collection.  Security rules will either allow that request for all documents, or reject it entirely.  They will not provide a subset of those documents that match some criteria.  If security rules will not scan the contents of all documents to check their values - that will not scale massively as Firestore requires.

There is unfortunately a second problem here in that there is actually no way to make your query match your rules.  Firestore doesn't provide a way to filter for the existence of a field in documents.  You can only filter on known field values that actually exist.  This means that you should consider alternatives to your data modeling.  Perhaps you want to add a boolean field called "hasProgramId" and make sure it **always** has a value of true or false so that it can be used in both rules and query filters.

So your query could be like this:

```
const res = await firebase.firestore()
    .collection("Routines")
    .where("hasProgramId", "==", true)
    .get();
```

And your rules can check to make sure the client request is valid like this:

```
match /Routines/{routineId=**} {
    allow write: if false;
    allow read: if resource.data.hasProgramId;
}
```

Comment: I read the article but as I understood it, I should not get any documents back, when loading the entire collection, because some do not satisfy the rule. However in my case, I get all document of my collections (even the ones that have a `programId`).

Comment: If you think there is a bug with security rules, you can report that to Firebase support.  I can't explain why that is, but I know that what you're hoping to do with the rule just isn't possible.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support